# Compare multiple file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a set of directories with `n` number of files, I need to compare each of those files (within one directory) and find if there is any difference in them. 
I tried `filecmp` and `difflib` but they only support two files.

Is there anything else I can do to compare/diff the files ?

This file contain hosts name

```
--------------------------------
Example :- Dir -> Server.1
                    |-> file1
                    |-> file2
                    |-> file3


file1 <- host1 
         host2
         host3

file2 <- host1 
         host2 
         host3 
         host4

file3 <- host1 
         host2 
         host3
```

Comment: The number of possible differences increases rapidly with the number of files you compare. With three files, there would be three diff files (1 vs. 2, 2 vs. 3, 1 vs. 3), with four, you already have six (1 vs. 2, 1 vs. 3, 1 vs. 4, 2 vs. 3, 2 vs. 4, 3 vs. 4) etc...

Comment: You can put something together with `pairwise` from [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)

Comment: You have to make a pair-wise comparisons of the files? If so, you are on a good way with `filecmp`. You also need the differences, or you only need the info, if they are different?

Comment: @TimPietzcker ... it doesn't increase exponentially. It increases quadratically. If you have `n` files, then you need to make `n(n-1)/2` comparisons.

Comment: @Nejc: You're right, I already retracted that part of my comment after doing a few tests. The number of combinations (starting from 3) increases like this: 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171 etc.

Comment: If your files are list of hosts you can read them row by row and build `set`s so you could check for intersections.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd share how combining the md5 hash compare with os.path.walk() can help you ferret out all the duplicates in a directory tree. The larger the number of directories and files gets, the more helpful it might be to first sort files by size to rule out any files that can't duplicates because they are of different size. Hope this helps.

```
import os, sys
from hashlib import md5

nonDirFiles = []

def crawler(arg, dirname, fnames):
    '''Crawls directory 'dirname' and creates global 
    list of paths (nonDirFiles) that are files, not directories'''
    d = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(dirname)

    global nonDirFiles
    for f in fnames:
        if not os.path.isfile(f):

            continue
        else:       
            nonDirFiles.append(os.path.join(dirname, f))
    os.chdir(d)

def startCrawl():
    x = raw_input("Enter Dir: ")
    print 'Scanning directory "%s"....' %x
    os.path.walk(x, crawler, nonDirFiles)

def findDupes():
    dupes = []
    outFiles = []
    hashes = {}
    for fileName in nonDirFiles:
        print 'Scanning file "%s"...' % fileName
        f = file(fileName, 'r')
        hasher = md5()
        data = f.read()
        hasher.update(data)
        hashValue = hasher.digest()

        if hashes.has_key(hashValue):

            dupes.append(fileName)
        else:
            hashes[hashValue] = fileName

    return dupes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startCrawl()
    dupes = findDupes()
    print "These files are duplicates:"
    for d in dupes:print d
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't specify whether you need to determine the differences or only find which files are the same/different - so I will focus on grouping together like files.

You can use hashing to group identical files together:

```
from hashlib import md5
from pprint import pprint

def get_filenames():
    return ('file1', 'file2', 'file3')

hashes = {}
for f in get_filenames():
    hd = md5(open(f).read()).hexdigest()
    hashes[hd] = hashes.get(hd, []) + [f]

pprint(hashes)
{'420248eb2e8226ac441cb7516fb7ff23': ['file2'],
 '4f2d7139dc1aa23235e7fad418a5bd10': ['file1', 'file3']}
```

Given that your files contain lists of host names you might like to sort the files beforehand so that, for example,

```
file1 <- host1 
         host2
         host3
```

and

```
file3 <- host3 
         host2
         host1
```

are considered equivalent.