# How to diff from multiple read file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to diff with three files in Python on Linux.

I've got (a,b,c) three files such as

```
/work/a
/work/b
/work/c

The name of a file consists of absolute paths of some hex files 
(for example of a file)
user/work/test0/.../bin0.hex
user/work/test0/.../bin1.hex
user/work/test0/.../bin2.hex
user/work/test0/.../bin3.hex
...

The name of b file consists of absolute path of some hex files
(for example of b file)
user/work/test1/.../bin0.hex
user/work/test1/.../bin1.hex
user/work/test1/.../bin2.hex
user/work/test1/.../bin3.hex
...

The name of c file consists of absolute path of some hex files
(for example of c)
user/work/test2/.../bin0.hex
user/work/test2/.../bin1.hex
user/work/test2/.../bin2.hex
user/work/test2/.../bin3.hex
...

and each hex file contains the string list such as 
[    0] A4B232
[    1] 14B2F2
[    2] 1472F1
...
```

I want to diff the each 3 hex files from a, b and c file.

so I started coding as below in Python. so far, I've got successfully save the data into the global variables.

```
arr_s_line1 = []
arr_s_line2 = []
arr_s_line3 = []

#def dfile():
# with open('a') as f1:
#  f_lines1 = f1.read().splitlines();
#  for f_line1 in f_lines1:
#   with open(f_line1) as f2:
#    s_line1 = f2.read().splitlines()
#   for s_line1 in s_lines1:
#    arr_s_line1.append(s_line1)

def prtf():
 with open ('a') as fprtfa:
  linesa = fprtfa.read().splitlines()
 with open ('b') as fprtfb:
  linesb = fprtfb.read().splitlines()
 with open ('c') as fprtfc:
  linesc = fprtfc.read().splitlines()

 for linea in linesa :
  with open(linea) as fa:
   s_linesa = fa.read().splitlines()
   for s_linea in s_linesa:
    arr_s_line1.append(s_linea)

 for lineb in linesb :
  with open(lineb) as fb:
   s_linesb = fb.read().splitlines()
   for s_lineb in s_linesb:
    arr_s_line2.append(s_lineb)

 for linec in linesc :
  with open(linec) as fc:
   s_linesc = fc.read().splitlines()
   for s_linec in s_linesc:
    arr_s_line3.append(s_linec)


if __name__== "__main__":

 prtf()
```

and I want to diff among with arr_s_line1[i] & arr_s_line2[i] &arr_s_line3[i]) to know whether there is mismatch or not. and If there is a happening of mismatch then I want to print the name of mismatched file and where line. How to diff from multiple read file in python?

Especially, the problem of this way is when I run a large amount of files, many memories required to run. so I want to avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare multiple files in python and show all the name variations associated with SSN's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010226/how-to-compare-multiple-files-in-python-and-show-all-the-name-variations-associa) ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673184/multiple-files-comparing-using-python ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477740/compare-multiple-file-in-python